# Sampson Distance using opencv, c++

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I'm trying to calculate the `Sampson distance`, the distance from a point to it's corresponding epipolar line which I will use as an error metric later. I'm using `opencv 3.1`, `c++`, and `windows-10 visual studio 14`.

But the function sampsonDistance crashes the code:

```
Point3f point1 = Point3f(keypoints_1[good_matches[iP].queryIdx].pt.x, keypoints_1[good_matches[iP].queryIdx].pt.y, 1.0);
Point3f point2 = Point3f(keypoints_2[good_matches[iP].trainIdx].pt.x, keypoints_2[good_matches[iP].trainIdx].pt.y, 1.0);            

Mat pt1(point1);
Mat pt2(point2);

double sampsonD = sampsonDistance(pt1, pt2, Flist[iF])
```

I get the error message:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (_pt1.type() == CV_64F && _pt1.type() == CV_64F && _F.type() == CV_64F) in cv::sampsonDistance, file D:\opencv\sources\modules\calib3d\src\fundam.cpp, line 1043
```

The documentation says:

```
double cv::sampsonDistance  ( InputArray  pt1,  
InputArray  pt2,  
InputArray  F  
)
```

How do I use this function, I don't really understand the usage of the input array, in the above I convert a 3d point into what I believe is 2D homogeneous coordinates stored as a cv::Mat. The fundamental matrix is stored at a 3x3 cv::Mat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, the points and the fundamental matrix have to be `CV_64F` (double type).

For the points, it should be:

```
Point3d point1 = Point3d(keypoints_1[good_matches[iP].queryIdx].pt.x, keypoints_1[good_matches[iP].queryIdx].pt.y, 1.0);
Point3d point2 = Point3d(keypoints_2[good_matches[iP].trainIdx].pt.x, keypoints_2[good_matches[iP].trainIdx].pt.y, 1.0);
```

Comment: Thanks that seemed to fix it.